# How do I reload screen using the react testing library?

Tags: testing, integration-testing, react-testing-library

I am using the react testing library (https://testing-library.com/) and I am having an issue where in between tests I change global values (that change the layout of the app) but the screen will not do these updates.
My temporary solution is to import a file where I set the globals but that will only work once for the whole file. I need some way to refresh the page with the new global values.

Comment: Share the link for the lib you are using

Comment: https://testing-library.com/

Comment: Did you mean "rerender" or "reload"? Please provide the code you have done